# Proper order of jQuery script? Hide/Show function not working in live version but works as stand alone Fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a couple jQuery functions that are working properly - A fadeIn of a fixed logo and navigation menu bound to a page scroll, as well as a lightbox and scrollbar fix for Firefox tied to (document).ready.

I'm trying to add the ability to hide and/or show a couple of div's tied to a click.

As a stand-alone function, I have it working properly as a fiddle...

[Working JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4SDesignStudio/680ez799/2/)

The problem is I'm a learning my way through jQuery as I go and I'm not sure of what the proper order is to call the functions in my script at the bottom of my page.

My logic tells me to include it under the (document).ready piece, but when I insert the working script from the fiddle, it not only doesn't work but also screws up the rest of my functions.

Current working script without hide/show function (Updated per comments):

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $(".main-links").fadeIn();
    $(".header-logo").fadeIn();

} else {
    $(".main-links").hide();
    $(".header-logo").hide();

    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    $('.scroll-pane2').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

The way I've tried inserting the additional function is like this:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $(".main-links").fadeIn();
    $(".header-logo").fadeIn();

} else {
    $(".main-links").hide();
    $(".header-logo").hide();

    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    $('.scroll-pane2').jScrollPane();

    $('#menu-switch1').on('click', function(event) {        
       $('#main-tasting-menu').toggle('show');
       $('#dessert-tasting-menu').toggle('hide');   
   });

   $('#menu-switch2').on('click', function(event) {        
     $('#main-tasting-menu').toggle('hide');
     $('#dessert-tasting-menu').toggle('show');

});
</script>
```

When I do this, the toggle doesn't work like it does in my fiddle, it kills my scroll-pane2 and adds a horizontal scroll that shouldn't be there on .scroll-pane1.

Is there something obvious that I'm overlooking because of my shitty knowledge of jQuery?

HTML  Section (inventory of scripts?):

```
<script src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/nivo-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href="themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">



    <!-- jScrollPane CSS for Firefox scrollbar fix (applied to all browsers) -->
    <link href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    <!-- Mousewheel support for jScrollPane scrollbar fix for FireFox and IE -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if you are using a recent version of jQuery `live()` was deprecated a long time ago . It was still available in version in fiddle but frowned upon since `on()` is far more reliable. Look for errors in browser console

Comment: I'm hosting jQuery version 1.11.0 locally.  I have updated to on() to clean it up.  Thank you for the good info but unfortunately, it's not solving my problem.

Comment: list inventory of scripts and order they are in. Also confirm status of errors thrown in browser console

Comment: Error thrown is - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.  When you say inventory of scripts, I'm assuming you meant the links within my <head>.  I'll update my original post with that info but if you were looking for something else, let me know.

Comment: ahhh...that error is the problem. Numerous online syntax linting tools that you can use to validate your code with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is a syntax error in your example when you added the click handlers for `#menu-switch`. You need to close the function and the call to live, like below. Notice the extra `})` closing each call to `live()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    $('.scroll-pane2').jScrollPane();

    $('#menu-switch1').live('click', function(event) {        
       $('#main-tasting-menu').toggle('show');
       $('#dessert-tasting-menu').toggle('hide');
    });  

   $('#menu-switch2').live('click', function(event) {        
     $('#main-tasting-menu').toggle('hide');
     $('#dessert-tasting-menu').toggle('show');
   });

});
```

And there are a couple more things you might want to consider. You will want to wrap everything inside the `$(document).ready()` call, because that will ensure that jQuery and the DOM are ready for action. And as charlietfl mentioned in a comment above, the `live()` method [was deprecated in version 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/). If you are using a version > 1.7, then you'll want to use `on()` instead. Here's an updated version of the whole thing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Cache the items you need to use inside different functions.
  // This is so that you don't have to call the jQuery method
  // on every user action.
  var $mainLinks = $('.main-links');
  var $headerLogo = $('.header-logo');
  var $mainTastingMenu = $('#main-tasting-menu');
  var $dessertTastingMenu = $('#dessertTastingMenu');
  var $menuSwitch_1 = $('#menu-switch1');
  var $menuSwitch_2 = $('#menu-switch2');

  // Setup your plugins
  $('.lightbox').nivoLightbox();
  $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
  $('.scroll-pane2').jScrollPane();

  // Setup your event handlers

  $menuSwitch_1.on('click', function(event) {
    $mainTastingMenu.toggle('show');
    $dessertTastingMenu.toggle('hide');
  });

  $menuSwitch_2.on('click', function(event) {        
    $mainTastingMenu.toggle('hide');
    $dessertTastingMenu.toggle('show');
  });

  // I made this handler match the ones above for consistency
  $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {

      $mainLinks.fadeIn();
      $headerLogo.fadeIn();

    } else {

      $mainLinks.hide();
      $headerLogo.hide();
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I've updated accordingly.  Unfortunately, still not firing correctly.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a cleanup of things. If that doesn't help, then let me know what kind of error you see in your Javascript console.

Comment: @grammer - I can't even tell you how much I appreciate the detailed feedback.  That fixed all of my issues and maybe more importantly, helped me understand why and how.  Thanks!